# passing argument 4 of ‘addsum’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Tags: c

Thank you to anyone reading this , I have a problem with a part of my code , I'm learning to do functions, and functions that are named enter and get_random work fine.

Now i want to add function addsum, but for some reason when i run the code with it, the debugger stops me when the for loop of checking the column finishes and the for loop that loops row should start .

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? i only know the bare essentials of pointers, maybe that is the solution to my problems? thanks in advance.

This is the message from the debugger

passing argument 4 of ‘addsum’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> // libraries added from example
#include<time.h>
//(*) For a square matrix calculate the sum of elements under the main diagonal excluding it.
#define A -10
#define B 10

int main(){
    void enter(int *x,int *y);
    int get_random(int lbound,int ubound);
    int addsum(int ro, int co, int s, int arr[ro][co]);
    int r;
    int c;
    int row,col,sum=0;
    enter(&r,&c);
    srand48(time(NULL)); //Call srand48 with current time reported by `time` casted to a long integer.
    // srand48 is used to reinitialize the most recent 48-bit value in this storage
    int array[r][c]; // we decided its gonna be r rows and c columns
    for (row=0;row<r;++row) // we cycle numeration of rows of matrix
    {
        for(col=0;col<c;col++) // we cycle numeration of columns of matrix
        {
            array[row][col]=get_random(B,A);// filling array with random numbers, taken from example
            printf("%d ",array[row][col]);
            addsum(row, col, sum, array[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n"); // this is to break line after row 1,2 col 3, so it looks nicer
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("sum of array: %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
void enter(int *x,int *y){ // we have to use pointers if we want more then one return from a function

    printf("How man rows in array?  "); 
    scanf("%d", x); // we use x instead of &x because we need the adress of the number not the value
    printf("How man columns in array? ");
    scanf("%d", y); // we use y instead of &y because we need the adress of the number not the value

}
int get_random(int lbound,int ubound)
{
    return rand()%(ubound-lbound+1)+lbound; // function for generating random numbers
    }
int addsum(int ro, int co, int s, int arr[ro][co])
{
    if (ro>co){ //since we want the sum numbers below the diagonal row>col must be true
        s=s+arr[ro][co];// if row>col than we add the number to our sum
        return s; 
    }
}
```

I have tried to rewrite the function in several different ways, but i dont think its my syntax thats the problem.

Comment: `addsum(row, col, sum, array[row][col]);` is bad. That is not the array but one out-of-range element. Anyway, you can't redefine array dimensions dynamically. The array is size `r` and `c` not `row` and `col`.

Comment: Notice how the return value is NOT captured into `int sum`?

Comment: Function prototypes are conventionally typed OUTSIDE of any function... Does this compile without too many warnings?

Comment: `addsum()` is a pointless complexity. It's purpose is nothing more than an `if` statement. While it's admirable to grapple with how one passes arrays to functions, this particular example has clouded what you hope to achieve. Strive to write clean, clear, concise code instead. If you want to sum some "wedge" of elements, do that entire operation in a single block, not broken into needless function calls. Fill the array, then call a function that delivers the result that you want from the entire array.